how to add a maximum travel length for the largest route in Vehicle routing problem - Google OR Tools
I am solving the capacitated vehicle routing problem using OR Tools (Python). I just want to add a constraint, i.e., an upper limit on the length of the largest route. Can someone please let me know how I can do it in the code below.
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f"Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}")
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = f"Route for vehicle {vehicle_id}:\n"
        route_distance = 0
        route_load = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            route_load += data["demands"][node_index]
            plan_output += f" {node_index} Load({route_load}) -> "
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id
            )
        plan_output += f" {manager.IndexToNode(index)} Load({route_load})\n"
        plan_output += f"Distance of the route: {route_distance}m\n"
        plan_output += f"Load of the route: {route_load}\n"
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
        total_load += route_load
    print(f"Total distance of all routes: {total_distance}m")
    print(f"Total load of all routes: {total_load}")


def main():
    """Solve the CVRP problem."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data["distance_matrix"]), data["num_vehicles"], data["depot"]
    )

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # Create and register a transit callback.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data["distance_matrix"][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Capacity constraint.
    def demand_callback(from_index):
        """Returns the demand of the node."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        return data["demands"][from_node]

    demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)
    routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
        demand_callback_index,
        0,  # null capacity slack
        data["vehicle_capacities"],  # vehicle maximum capacities
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        "Capacity",
    )

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
    )
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I’m voting to close this question because there was no effort. Just copy paste the distributed example and a question.

So put an upper limit on the length of all routes.
This can be done by constraining the transit_distance cumul var of the end of each route.
I recommend putting a soft limit instead of a hard one.
Now, to add a hard limit and the total distance:

if the max length need to be less than X, then all routes needs to be less than X.
Simply create a dimension with the transit_callback_index, and use the #max size attribute to specify the max length.


I can not put an upper limit on the length of all routes. I am solving an optimization problem. The constraint is that length of the longest route should be less than or equal to a given number. Please help me with a python code for this.

routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,
    1000, #your upper limit on the length of the largest route 
    True,
    "Distance")

